# TableLayout looks fine on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, android-emulator, tablelayout

I'm running my code on the emulator with Android 2.2 and it works fine. But when I put it on my device (Galaxy S 2.3.3) the main screen that should show a list of elements in a table - stays blank. Toasts however are shown and also the header with the app_name

The table is made of a button (defined in XML) and a list of elements loaded from a DB.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:text="@string/add_button" android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here the code:

```
public void showList(Cursor c){

    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
    table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayoutMain);

    do {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);           
        final int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapter.KEY_ROWID));
        tr.setId(id);           
        tr.setBackgroundColor(ROW_COLOR);           

        tr.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                //do stuff

                return true;
            }
        });

        tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do other stuff
            }
        });                     

        TextView txt = getText(active, id, name);
        tr.addView(txt);
        table.addView(tr);          

    } while (c.moveToNext());
    c.close();
}
```

I wasn't sure if the mixing between XML definitions and programatically adding elements would work. But I have tried various combinations and can say that they both work equally bad. i.e. fine on the emulator and bad on the device.
I have also created a virtual device with android 2.3.3 where the code runs fine as well... so I guess it can't be the Android version. Any thoughts?

Comment: where is declaration of "ROW_COLOR"?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: that is a constant declared in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, got it to work by using a Relative layout as parent for the TableLayout. Not exactly what I wanted but it works...